# How to convert to left hand coordinate system

Tags: javascript, function, three.js, coordinate-systems

I have an application that loads a model.

my server sends back response information about what axis to use for the right and up orientation in the following format:

[server format:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5UPw.png)

I am using three js which uses the right hand coordinate system so i need to convert what ever the server says to this system.

upAxis and rightAxis is always returned and possible values are: x_positive, x_negative, y_positive, y_negative, z_positive, z_negative.

i need to switch from the left hand coordinates the server sends me to right hand coordinates in three js.

I created a starter code but i am not sure what else to do or what else needs to be done:

```
function rotate() {
    var a = state.currentInfo; //stores the values for upAxis and rightAxis

    //EXAMPLE FOR X axis
    if (a.upAxis === "x_positive") {
        //object itself
        scene.rotation.x = -90 * Math.PI/180;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to determine the orientation you want with the `up` property, for example :

```
camera.up.set( 1, 0, 0 );
```

Comment: what does this point the axisup to? x? also can you provide a solution for both axisup and axisright for all posibilities (x,y,z,-x,-y,-z)